# Error en Android al cargar un RecyclerView

Tags: android

*estoy creando una app en Android Studio. Al darle ejecutar, automaticamente cierra el incio de la app y me muestra la siguiente falla. No logro entender que es lo que esta pasando, ya que el codigo esta alojado en un github y al propietario le funciona lo mas bien.
el editor no señala ninguna linea en rojo, por lo que esto tambien me desconcierta un poco*

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: nachitosmail.android.seccion_03_recyclerview, PID: 4079
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{nachitosmail.android.seccion_03_recyclerview/nachitosmail.android.seccion_03_recyclerview.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
```

this is the main activity

```
package nachitosmail.android.seccion_03_recyclerview;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<String> names;

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    // Puede ser declarado como 'RecyclerView.Adapter' o como nuetra clase adaptador 'MyAdapter'
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    private int counter = 0;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        names = this.getAllNames();

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        // mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
        // mLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

        // Implementamos nuestro OnItemClickListener propio, sobreescribiendo el método que nosotros
        // definimos en el adaptador, y recibiendo los parámetros que necesitamos
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(names, R.layout.recycler_view_item, new MyAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(String name, int position) {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, name + " - " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                deleteName(position);
            }
        });

        // Lo usamos en caso de que sepamos que el layout no va a cambiar de tamaño, mejorando la performance
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        // Añade un efecto por defecto, si le pasamos null lo desactivamos por completo
        mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        // Enlazamos el layout manager y adaptor directamente al recycler view
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.add_name:
                this.addName(0);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private List<String> getAllNames() {
        return new ArrayList<String>() {{
            add("Alejandro");
            add("Jose");
            add("Barrera");
            add("Ruben");
            add("Antonio");
        }};
    }

    private void addName(int position) {
        names.add(position, "New name " + (++counter));
        // Notificamos de un nuevo item insertado en nuestra colección
        mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(position);
        // Hacemos scroll hacia lo posición donde el nuevo elemento se aloja
        mLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(position);
    }

    private void deleteName(int position) {
        names.remove(position);
        // Notificamos de un item borrado en nuestra colección
        mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
}
```

este es MyAdapter

```
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

    import java.util.List;

    /**
     * Created by Alejandro on 3/9/16.
     */
    public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

        private List<String> names;
        private int layout;
        private OnItemClickListener itemClickListener;


        public MyAdapter(List<String> names, int layout, OnItemClickListener listener) {
            this.names = names;
            this.layout = layout;
            this.itemClickListener = listener;
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            // Inflamos el layout y se lo pasamos al constructor del ViewHolder, donde manejaremos
            // toda la lógica como extraer los datos, referencias...
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(layout, parent, false);
            ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
            return vh;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            // Llamamos al método Bind del ViewHolder pasándole objeto y listener
            holder.bind(names.get(position), itemClickListener);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return names.size();
        }

        public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            // Elementos UI a rellenar
            public TextView textViewName;

            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                // Recibe la View completa. La pasa al constructor padre y enlazamos referencias UI
                // con nuestras propiedades ViewHolder declaradas justo arriba.
                super(itemView);
                this.textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            }

            public void bind(final String name, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
                // Procesamos los datos a renderizar
                this.textViewName.setText(name);
                // Definimos que por cada elemento de nuestro recycler view, tenemos un click listener
                // que se comporta de la siguiente manera...
                itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        // ... pasamos nuestro objeto modelo (este caso String) y posición
                        listener.onItemClick(name, getAdapterPosition());
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        // Declaramos nuestra interfaz con el/los método/s a implementar
        public interface OnItemClickListener {
            void onItemClick(String name, int position);
        }


    }
```

el archivo se compone de una actividad mainActivity y una de MyAdapter. Ademas, tengo un layout general y un layout para el recyclerview, los cuales no deberian marcar error, son sencillos, o si?

este es el layout activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<!--    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />-->

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Lo he solucionado declarando el activity de la siguiente manera:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Al parecer, android utiliza otra version de layout, esto me lo mencionaron mirando el constraintLayout

Comment: Si pudieras agregar tu código, que por lo que veo en el error estar cargando mal la vista a un reciclar View.

Comment: Es relativamente facil descifrar lo que sucede pero para una respuesta completa agrega el layout que carga MainActivity mediante setContentView

Comment: El error que te ocurre es que no puede cargar el RecyclerView de tu actividad.
Concretamente, el error se encuentra en la línea 18 de tu archivo de actividad .xml, ya que no puede encontrar el objeto. La solución es que revises cómo cargas ese objeto y si estás añadiendo las librerias correctas para la carga del mismo.
Si has descargado los archivos de Github, deberías tratar de hacer un make del proyecto y comprobar que no hay ningún error y efectivamente estás añadiendo la librería correcta para ese widget.

Comment: he cargado los codigos correspondientes.

Comment: El proyecto parece migrado a AndroidX ya que es la versión de Constraint que estás usando y en cambio se está quejando de la de support v7. Prueba a emplezar la RecyclerView de AndroidX: <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView />

Comment: Ignacio, para mejorar el contenido de la comunidad, si alguien te ha comentado la solución y te funciona, al lado del comentario de esa persona puedes darle un positivo, lo que indica que el comentario es útil.  Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema indicado en el mensaje:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Binary XML
>   file line #18: Error inflating class
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView this is the main activity

Se debe a que estas usando AndroidX  y estas tratando de cargar una vista de la library de soporte, lo cual en tu proyecto es incorrecto:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
```

debes usar AndroidX, realiza el cambio a:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes agregar los constraints que le restan al `RecyclerView` dentro del `ConstriantLayout`, si necesitas que cubra toda la pantalla agrega:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
```

Y eso debe de resolver el problema; si lees el error dice que el problema esta en el XML cuando trata de inflar esta vista.